# Line spinner using css animation

Tags: css, css-animations, spin.js

Is there any way to add line spinner (from spin.js - https://spin.js.org) using plain css animation without using javascript (example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp)?

Comment: why you need the spin.js if you have the code on the w3school link ?

Comment: I wanted different type of spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, thanks for this article: [click to see](https://www.catswhocode.com/blog/stunning-examples-of-css-loaders)

For simpliest understanding, here is code snippet:

```css
/**
 * (C)Leanest CSS spinner ever
 */

@keyframes spin {
 to { transform: rotate(1turn); }
}

.progress {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 5em;
 height: 5em;
 margin: 0 .5em;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-indent: 999em;
 overflow: hidden;
 animation: spin 1s infinite steps(8);
}

.small.progress {
 font-size: 6px;
}

.large.progress {
 font-size: 24px;
}

.progress:before,
.progress:after,
.progress > div:before,
.progress > div:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 2.25em; /* (container width - part width)/2  */
 width: .5em;
 height: 1.5em;
 border-radius: .2em;
 background: #eee;
 box-shadow: 0 3.5em #eee; /* container height - part height */
 transform-origin: 50% 2.5em; /* container height / 2 */
}

.progress:before {
 background: #555;
}

.progress:after {
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 background: #777;
}

.progress > div:before {
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 background: #999;
}

.progress > div:after {
 transform: rotate(-135deg);
 background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>How To Create A Loader</h2>


<div class="progress"><div>Loading…</div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

And [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sk34s4mx/1/)

Comment: That's great, not sure I missed it in my research. Many thanks for your quick reply.